# Wired transfer of live video between 2 raspberry pi's

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, raspicam, streaming-video

How can I send a live video from a Raspberry pi to another Raspberry pi, using an optical fibre, not using WiFi or other wireless communications?
I need to send a live video recorded by a camera, connected to a raspberry pi, to another raspberry pi board, & there shouldn’t be much time lag. My requirement is to send it through a wired medium only.

Comment: Using optical fibre is not going to make any difference. I suggest you look into the maximum throughput of the USB ports and Ethernet port on the Pi 2 and 3. You are going to see much more latency due to the Pi's ability to process data rather than latency due to data transfer. A decent Cat6a Ethernet cable will probably be more than adequate.

Comment: Unless you need to push the data over a long distance.

Answer (score 2):

Live video shouldn't be a problem using [Gstreamer and RTSP](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp.html). All that is built into GST and there are quite a few tutorials out there. Wired over short ( <100 meters ) distance isn't a problem as Dark Vader mentioned - a decent length of Cat6a will handle this.

Over longer distances, or if you absolutely have to use fibre, you can look into media converters (something like [this](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/MC110CS.html) - as an example). These typically take ethernet input and provider multi-mode or single-mode fibre output. There are plenty of fast ethernet ones available that make claims of 2km to 100km (thats hundred!). If you only ever need this for a Pi you wouldn't need gigabit since the Pi cannot provide that speed anyway.

Its probably best to test the RTSP stuff over ethernet first then ramp up the distances if that provides a good enough experience before commiting to hardware solutions to the distance.